# 301 Redirect with variables using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I upgrade my company's website to a new one while changing page names and variable names. So I want to redirect this dynamic page

http://www.example.com/companies.php?supplier=test1&manufacturer=Test2

to this

http://www.example.com/supplier/test2

NOTE: I need to lowercase the test2 variable

Edit: I have written this code. The page redirects to new page name but variables don't

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} supplier=([^/]+)&manufacturer=([^/]+)
RewriteRule ^/?companies\.php$ supplier/$2
```

Comment: What do you mean by variables? Are you referring to query strings?

Comment: Yes ! I mean Get variables

Comment: So you want the query strings to keep stay on url? `/supplier/test2?supplier=test1&manufacturer=Test2`?

Comment: No. The query strings need to be tranformed as shown in the example. No use of supplier Get and lower case manufacturer Get. I apologise for my English :)